# Filtering query results where subquery returns no rows

Tags: soql, subquery

I'm trying to filter out query results when a subquery doesn't return rows, however, I'm still getting null results... Will someone please tell me what I need to do differently?

```
SELECT afc.ID, (
    SELECT Id, Name, Billing_Item__c, Billing_Item__r.Finalized__c, Type__c, Amount__c, 
           Payment_Remission__c, Agent__c, Affiliate_Contract__c, State__c 
    FROM Plan_Split_Disbursements__r
    WHERE Billing_Item__r.Finalized__c != null
    AND Type__c = 'Commission'
    AND State__c != 'Paid' 
    AND Issued_Date__c = null 
    AND Payment_Remission__c = null 
    ) 
FROM Affiliate_Contract__c afc
WHERE afc.Id IN (SELECT Affiliate_Contract__c FROM Plan_Split_Disbursement__c )
```

I'm getting something like this:

[image: Example of query results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting rows in your query which do not have rendered children is that your `WHERE` join is unfiltered, despite the filters on your `SELECT` join. If you want the query to only return rows which have matching children, the two joins need the same `WHERE` filters.

```
SELECT Id, (
    SELECT ...
    FROM Plan_Split_Disbursements__r
    WHERE ...
) 
FROM Affiliate_Contract__c
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Affiliate_Contract__c FROM Plan_Split_Disbursement__c
    WHERE Billing_Item__r.Finalized__c != null
    AND Type__c = 'Commission'
    AND State__c != 'Paid' 
    AND Issued_Date__c = null 
    AND Payment_Remission__c = null
)
```

Comment: This is what I thought. The confusion is when I would try to select the fields it didn't work... It appears you don't have to select the fields when you select "in".. Thank you.

Comment: When you do a filter join, your `SELECT` clause must contain only one field, and that field must be an Id, Lookup, or Master Detail field pointing to the correct object. When you do a join to actually `SELECT` those child objects, you can select any fields you wish.

Comment: Thank you for this.